# Groovy template render error when it contains words

Tags: templates, groovy, spring-boot

I used groovy template in my spring framework project. My template is

```
li(role: 'presentation') { a(href: 'url-test') { yield "首页"}}
```

the result of rendering is

```
<li role='presentation'><a href='book/search'>??</a></li>
```

And my file's encoding is utf-8, My site also using utf-8. It was ok in other page which not use groovy template.

What's problem in my project. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a `<meta>` tag in your code, then try adding this:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

That should do the trick :).
Chinese text doesn't play well with no `<meta>` tag.

Comment: I have written this in my template file

Comment: Perhaps, groovy doesn't like chinese?